# Drupal: Creating a special template file to my forms affects my css, which won´t load

Tags: php, css, templates, drupal, edit

I've removed the `<?php print $title; ?>` in my page tpl in Drupal 6.
That way, I'm creating a special template for each nodetype, where I can set the title (or not) in my own way (it's different for each content type).

The thing is that with that action, I've also removed the title in node/add forms (which is not good).

I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538600/how-can-i-theme-the-template-for-edit-or-add-a-node-for-a-specific-content-type) a solution of that problem, so, I've added this function to a new module:

```
function modding_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if ((arg(0) == 'node') && (arg(1) == 'add')) {
    $vars['template_files'][] =  'node-add';
  }
}
```

That way, every time I did create a new node, the title would appear.

My node-add.tpl.php template looks like this:

```
<h1><?php print $title ?></h1>
<?php print $content ?>
```

**My problem now is that the style sheets won´t load, and I don´t understand why. It looks as ugly as it can get when no style whatsoever is loaded.**
I may add that I've cleared cache more than once, and as this is a testing site, all performance caching has been disabled.

**Please note that I´m telling you all this about my motivations, just in case you know a better solution to add the title to each node/add, node/edit form. Because I´m in a mess because of it.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve found the solution. Posting it here just in case it helps somebody else:

```
<?php 
      if ((arg(0) == 'node') && (arg(1) == 'add') || (arg(2) == 'edit')){
    $node = node_load(array('nid' => arg(1)));
    print $title;
    }
?>
```

[Thanks to nevets](http://drupal.org/node/1846094), who gave me the hint that I needed! :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Exclude node title](http://drupal.org/project/exclude_node_title) module and keep headaches for another problems :)
it's granular up to the node but you can set it up at the content type level

hope it helps

PR

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The thing is that I do show the title, but I add to it some text information that´s specific to each nodetype. In example: <?php print $title ?>ismo in one case pre-<?php print $title ?> in other case, and so on. That´s why I thought of harcoding that special information in the template (not the best solution, I know).